# Grouping percentages with value_counts and multiple columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, likert

I want to create a table of grouped percentages across multiple columns using value_counts(normalize=True). I want to do so similar to below, except adding in the "normalize=True" portion, but not sure how to do so using groupby.agg. Any thoughts on how to do so without adding many more lines of code? My real data has a ton of columns, with a scale of 1-5 in each except the grouping columns.

Example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['FR', 'FR', 'GER','GER'],
               'Foo': ['1', '2', '3', '1'],
               'Bar': ['5', '5', '3', '1'],
               'Baz': ['5', '1', '3', '4']})

df2=df.groupby('Country').agg(
{
'Foo': 'value_counts' ,
'Bar': 'value_counts',
'Baz': 'value_counts'
}
      )
```

Comment: what's the desired output

Comment: Matrix table with percentage of each value in each column in the count (so in this case, Country, then 1-5, then % of grouped total for Foo, Bar, and Baz)

Comment: Please post a dataframe example of the output

Comment: Actually ended up figuring it out. import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['FR', 'FR', 'GER','GER'],
               'Foo': ['1', '2', '3', '1'],
               'Bar': ['5', '5', '3', '1'],
               'Baz': ['5', '1', '3', '4']})

f=lambda x: x/x.sum()

df2=df.groupby('Country').agg(
{
'Foo': 'value_counts' ,
'Bar': 'value_counts',
'Baz': 'value_counts'
}
      ).groupby(level=0).apply(f).sort_index



df2

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Figured it out! Will close.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['FR', 'FR', 'GER','GER'],
               'Foo': ['1', '2', '3', '1'],
               'Bar': ['5', '5', '3', '1'],
               'Baz': ['5', '1', '3', '4']})

f=lambda x: x/x.sum()

df2=df.groupby('Country').agg(
{
'Foo': 'value_counts' ,
'Bar': 'value_counts',
'Baz': 'value_counts'
}
      ).groupby(level=0).apply(f).sort_index

df2
```